# Creating a numpy matrix without replacement in rows

Tags: python, numpy

I can easily use `np.random.choice` with `replace=False` to generate a 1D array without replacement.  However, I need to generate a *matrix* such that each row is without replacement, i.e.`[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]]`. `np.random.randint` is the obvious choice, but there's no provision for non-repetition in this function. I'd also rather not iteratively append new rows to a matrix, as I imagine this is rather inefficient. So, what is the most efficient way to generate my matrix?

Comment: "I'd also rather not iteratively append new rows to a matrix" this includes list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

You can first create your whole array and then use `np.random.shuffle` for shuffling your rows.

```
n = 3
data = np.arange(n*n).reshape(n, n) % n + 1
for row in data:
    np.random.shuffle(row)
```

Here, the modulo operator is used for producing numbers from 0 to (n-1) in each row.

---

As an alternative,

```
data = np.empty(shape=(3, 3))
```

reserves the memory for an empty array that can afterwards be filled more efficiently:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i,:] = np.random.choice(3, 3, replace=False) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension:

```
data = np.array([np.random.choice([1,2,3], 3, replace=False) for _ in range(3)])
```